# how to find dynamic dom loaded time from server response in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I tried to load dynamic elements based upon ajax server response, then I need measure how long will take to render dynamic element after server response, If any tools is there like chrome extension or javascript code, please tell me, thanks advance

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: in that time line I can find only server response time, but I need to find time between server response success and dom rendered complete

Comment: Ah, for that you would need to save your own timestamps and compare them. It should be just a few milliseconds though, unless you're loading a ridiculous amount of data, which you shouldn't.

Comment: Google Chrome is **packed to the brim** with profiling tools in Dev Tools. Make sure you look for guides on how to use them.